Why are my Lilly Pilly (Acmena smithii) trees dropping leaves and dying?
I planted a series of Lilly Pilly (Acmena smithii) trees in spring two years ago to hide an ugly fence. We have very sandy soils but I mixed in some mulch to a depth of 50cm. The site is in full sun in summer and partial sun in winter. An automated irrigation system waters the plants three times a week. On hot days over summer I would supplement with additional watering. I've fertilized the plants in spring and autumn as instructed.
The same variety is mentioned in this post.
This variety is advertised as a fast growing plant. Initially the plants added between 10% and 30% to their height and appeared very healthy and covered with leaves and new growth. However, after six months they stopped growing and started losing a lot of leaves. They now appear very sparse, and several trees died.
The general pattern was starting at the leaves furthest from the main trunks and gradually moving closer, leaves would turn yellow, then dead/brown, then drop. This was worse in summer.
With recent heavy rains the plants started to grow new leaves (as shown in the image below) however the new growth was very limited and stopped.
I have consulted with local garden stores who have provided a mixed bag of fixes. One said this is perfectly normal, it was just a hot summer with too little water. Another said root rot from too much water. Another said a lack of fertilizer. Another said too much fertilizer.
There is no sign of psyllid infestation.
What is causing the plants to struggle and what can I do to help them?



Ideas: 1. Chose the dead-est one and dig it up(not pull out). Are the roots rotten(zero white roots)? 2. Do other plants flourish? They seem to. 3. Is pH correct. 6.4 to 7.5 is mostly in the range of parsley and IMHO shouldn't cause severe symptoms. There's always inexpensive sulfur or gypsum of course but I would recommend wood ash.
